# MAAS error with respect to node's BMC? How to activate debug logs?

Tags: juju, maas

New version of MAAS (1.7.3) still do not work for me. This strongly leads me to think that MAAS only works when Region Controller and Cluster Controller are in a router position, which is definitely not covering a general use case...

Since all my questions remain unanswered I am trying a last one before opening possibly bug reports...

How to solve the error message below.

```
Failed to query node's BMC — Node could not be queried node-... (...)    virsh failed with return code 1: Failed to login to virsh console.
```

All ssh keys are in place an new node can be power on/off without problem. Is this a bug?

Also in addition to the big lack of reasonably advanced documentation, I can't seem to find how to activate decent debug logs. Whatever is available as log is close to useless... Help on how to activate such debug logs would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

So your node is a VM, right?

MAAS will call virsh as the "maas" user, so ~maas/.ssh/id_rsa has to exist, be correct in terms of permissions and be a private key allowed to login on the host where the VM is running.

You can test it by becoming the maas user on the MAAS machine and trying to use virsh as MAAS would. For example:

```
sudo -H -u maas virsh -c qemu+ssh://you@<host-where-vm-is>/system list --all
```

Also note you need libvirt-bin installed on the MAAS server, since that's where the virsh command comes from. It's not a dependency of the MAAS packages.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Many thanks for you help but both cluster controllers have the right ssh keys and the command above runs successfully as maas user on both nodes. Upgraded to 1.8 and now no more error message but result is the same, deployment fails for what reason this is the question.

Answer (score 0):

If using power address 'qemu:///system', then add maas to the libvirtd group. I.e.:

```
# grep ^libvirtd /etc/group
libvirtd:x:112:maas
#
```

Reboot after applying this change as existing processes won't be in the new extra group.